# PHP Arrays Value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this array

print_r of the array

```
Array (
  [@attributes] => Array (
    [from] => 14073377593@s.whatsapp.net
    [id] => 1346984983-2
    [type] => chat
    [t] => 1346985039
  )
  [notify] => Array (
    [@attributes] => Array (
      [name] => SISTEMA SMS
    )
  )
  [request] => Array ( )
  [body] => Hola
)
```

and i need this value

```
[body] => Hola
```

someone can help me

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: This is a pretty much basic question which shows that you did not read the basics of php :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet being yours a multidimensional array, the `body` property is on the first level:

```
Array ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [from] => 14073377593@s.whatsapp.net
        [id] => 1346984983-2
        [type] => chat
        [t] => 1346985039 
    )
    [notify] => Array ( 
        [@attributes] => Array (
            [name] => SISTEMA SMS
        )
    ) 
    [request] => Array ( ) 
    [body] => Hola
)
```

So as a tip, wrap your `print_r` calls with [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre) HTML tag in order to read properly formatted output:

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($stuff);
 echo '</pre>';
```

It may seem silly, but it saves me a lot of time.

Comment: echo '<pre>'; help me a lot! thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $array['body'];
```

Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

It lives at `$array["body"]`

Have a look at something like this for a whirlwind tour of associative arrays: http://phpjournal.blogspot.co.uk/2004/11/php-associative-arrays.html